# React native useEffect cleanup function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am getting warning like
`Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`

I am using this code for useEffect cleanup but still i am getting same warning.

```
useEffect(() => {
        let isMounted = true;
        
        if (isMounted) {
            displayData();
        }
        
        return () => { isMounted = false };
    }, []);

const displayData = async () => {
        try {
            let userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
            setToken(userToken);
        }
        catch (error) {
            //console.log(error);
        }
}
```

any solution?

Comment: I think you'd better show displayData function codes. Does it have setState calls?

Comment: Why do you need a ismounted boolean, just call displayData, it will be called only once.

Comment: @DeepinderSingh i am  using ismounted boolea for useEffect cleanup.

Comment: @venomous31 you are not doing any cleanup, this would be useful when the useEffect is used without [], your useffect is called only once on init so you don't really need this here.
If is was without '[]' then this would be useful.

Comment: @DeepinderSingh not working.

Comment: @venomous31 It has nothing to do with cleanup, your method is returning and setting the state after the component is destoryed, so please check why your component is being destroyed before the API can be fulfulled.

Comment: You don't need any clean ups here remove the condition, `isMounted` variable, and the return function and see how that does. Your issue has nothing to do with the clean up function.

Comment: @abdou-tech after removing the conditions still  i am getting same warning.

Answer (score 0):

Your warning is `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.`

Because `AsyncStorage.getItem` is asynchronous, there is a chance that the component is already unmounted by the time it resolves with a value.

If you try to set the component's state with the value that `AsyncStorage.getItem` resolves (and it happens after the component has already been unmounted), you get this warning.

It doesn't look like `AsyncStorage.getItem` has a mechanism for canceling, so you should guard against the subsequent setting of state after the asynchronous `AsyncStorage.getItem` resolves its value.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export default function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;

    const displayData = async () => {
      try {
        let userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
        if (isMounted) {
          setToken(userToken);
        }
      } catch (error) {
      //console.log(error);
      }
    };


    displayData();

    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>...</>
  );
}
```

[Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@ksav/healthy-chip)

Comment: i want to call `displayData` outside of useEffect.

Comment: i am still confused by seeing your code. i am calling `displayData` on refresh also. that's why i am creating it outside of useEffect.

Comment: What do you mean by on refresh?

Comment: RefreshControl inside Scrollview

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @sizzle yes check the linked Snack